# How to take snapshot of website through shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script, centos

I have a website with login page. Now I want to generate a script to login into website and take snapshot of the screen through shell script. I'm using *centos 7.1* . Is there any tool or utility to do this all functionality?
We have created dials and want to take snapshot of those dials. The dial page will only be opened after login. Dials are created by svg elements. And I want command line utility so that I can take snapshot after every 5 mins and store the image at one location

Comment: Do you want a graphical rendering (so for example, something driving Firefox or Chrome to take a picture of its rendered page), or a text rendering (so `lynx -dump http://...`), or just a grab of the raw page (`wget http://...`)?

Comment: We have created dials and want to take snapshot of those dials. The dial page will only be opened after login. Dials are created by *svg*  elements. And I want command line utility so that I can take snapshot after every 5 mins and store the image at one location.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to download these svg images? And not the html per se?

Comment: I want to download the output of svg element as png image. I don't get svg code in html i.e when I see the source in browser I don't get the svg tag. I have to use firebug to see the svg code.

Answer (score 1):

For the login part as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948934/shell-script-to-login-into-a-website#10949063), it depends of what kind of authentication method this website implemented. It also depends of what kind of output you want.

About the screenshot you can give a try at **wkhtmltopdf**.
If you use a Debian based distro, you can install it as follow:

```
apt-cache search wkhtmltopdf
# if it is in your repos, install it :
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

Then you can try it and see if it gives nice outcome, Eg.:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238148/how-to-take-snapshot-of-website-through-shell-script fix_yournicequestion.pdf
```